# ASP.NET vNext DNX: Command not found when run from a script? Probably a path issue?

Tags: asp.net, linux, bash, dnx

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET vNext project on a Linux server, and even though I can start it from command line easily I cannot add the command to start it to "/etc/rc.local" because when the system starts it says "Could not find the command DNX." In an attempt to fix this, I tried to make a script (start.sh) the start the server, so that I could call the script from /etc/rc.local instead. Running the script gives the same error, but I can still copy the content of the script itself into the command line to get the exact same effect.

Here's a copy of the result of "echo $PATH": 
/root/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-rc1-final/bin:/root/.dnx/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Try to use full paths to files in a sctipt. Show contents of your rc.local .

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the full path in my script.